# Fix Unity Line Renderer for pointer drawing a jaggy line

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I think I'm using the standard Oculus setup from the SDK using the OVRCameraRig. I've also got a LaserPointer.

But inside VR on my Rift the line looks like this.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It used to be straight. Now it's not. I don't know what I changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Somehow "monoscopic" was checked in the OVRManager

[image]

No idea how that happened. Found it by looking through git diffs. **Unchecking** it fixed it.

Of course that brings up the question, what is that setting for if it messes up the rendering? I get it means you'd no longer get stereo 3D but I'd still expect lines to render straight!??!?